# Is there a bug in NSOperation in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, foundation

If I release an instance of `NSOperation` before sending `-init` to it I get a `segmentation fault`.

Reasons I think this is valid code:

- Apple does this in [its documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13).
- Gnustep does it in its [`implementation of NSNumber`](http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/base/tags/base-1_19_3/Source/NSNumber.m), so it's fairly certain that this is in Apple's code too. (At least was.)
- `NSObject`s `-init` doesn't do anything, therefore `-release`, which belongs to `NSObject` should be working before that.

```
// gcc -o test -L/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Foundation test.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSOperation *theOperation = [NSOperation alloc];
    [theOperation release];
}
```

- What do you think, is this a bug?
- Can you show me an example of another class that has the same behavior?
- Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @gs Please read my comment replying to yours on my answer :)

Comment: My point still stand :). I am sure NSOperation's `-init` allocs some pointer (to a structure or anything else). The pointer value is not set to `NULL` by the runtime, so calling `-release` frees a pointer that has not been initiated, and whose value my be 0 (aka somewhere you don't have access :D)

Answer (score 7):

Sending any message other than `init` to an object that has not been initialized is not valid code AFAIK. Call the superclass initializer and then release and I'm betting it won't crash (although having one class's initializer return a completely unrelated class strikes me as doubleplusungood).

Comment: Correct answer.  More details in mind.  I actually compiled a test project to make sure this wasn't a latent bug somewhere.  It isn't.

Comment: Returning a completely unrelated class is just for the example. I'm not doing this in my working code. Gnustep's `NSNumber` class also sends `-release` prior to initialization. `-initWithCoder` never calls `-init` as far is I know.

Comment: `initWithCoder:` methods do normally call through to super.

Comment: Apple does it in its documentation, that makes it valid I guess: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13

Comment: No, that makes Apple's documentation very slightly flawed. bbum demonstrated that doing as I said got rid of the crash.

Comment: Or Apple's implementation of NSOperation as many classes use this kind of code construct.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing remotely valid about that code.

Rewrite your -init as:

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self release];

        NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:6];
        return number;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Of course, the code is still nonsense, but it doesn't crash.

You must always call through to the super's initializer before messaging self. And you must always do it with the pattern shown above.

Comment: I changed the code to avoid more discussion about the code. Releasing before initializing is valid: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13

Answer (score 1):

I thought you need to initialize your superclass before calling release, but according to [this example](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13) in Apple's docs that's not the case.

So it may be a bug, but certainly not an important one.

Comment: I think you've found a documentation bug.

Answer (score 1):

My previou analysis was not really correct.

However, I want to point that this issue can happen with different classes. It actually depends on which class you're subclassing. Subclassing NSObject is no problem, but subclassing NSOperation, NSOperationQueue, and NSThread is an issue, for example.

And it happens because just like YOU might do, the classes you subclass might allocate stuff in their `-init` method. And that's also where you set to `nil` the variables you have not allocated yet (and might do so later in your code).

So, by calling `-release` on yourself without a previous `-init`, you might cause one of your parent classes to release object that it had not allocated. And they can't check if their object is `nil`, because it didn't even have the opportunity to init every object/value it needs.

This also might be the reason why releasing NSOperation without init worked on 10.5 and doesn't work on 10.6. The 10.6 implementation have been rewritten to use blocks and Grand Central Dispatch, and thus, their `init` and `dealloc` methods might have changed greatly, creating a different behavior on that piece of code.

Comment: Sending `-release` to a nil object shouldn't do anything. Also, freeing `NULL` pointers is supposed to do nothing. http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html Therefore, I think this is a bug.

Comment: @gs: Iknow free() and release work on NULL objects. However, when exactly do you want them to set the pointer to NULL / nil when you don't even let them init their object? (which is my point in this answer). Allocating the pointer on the stack doesn't set it to NULL / nil. That's why I think it's NOT a bug.

Comment: Ivars are automatically set to nil in alloc.

Comment: @Chuck: what about pure C attributes? Like structuers etc.? :)

Comment: They don't have to be freed in `-dealloc` as they are automatically removed when the object is deallocated. They work just like integers and the like.

Comment: @gs: simple structures, yes. But not pointers to structures. These are not freed on `-dealloc`, nor set to `NULL` without init.

Comment: You're right, my comment was based on pure C. I didn't know the Obj-C runtime set all ivar pointers to 0. That's good to know. My only last guess is that the documentation is wrong, and that even people at Apple are assument that if they go to through their `-dealloc` method, then it "obviously" went through `-init`. And then, all they need to do is `struct->value` and bam, segfault.

I guess you can file a bug, they will either fix the code, or the documentation :)

Comment: It actually crashes in `-release` and not in `-dealloc`, that's what surprised me too.

Comment: It is not impossible that Apple maintain an internal reference counting, as a kind of semaphore for example. Especially knowing the crash happens with NSOperationQueue, NSOperation, and NSThread :D.